# How to pass list of model pair in forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following classes:-

class A(...):
    ....

class B(...):
    objectA=models.ForeignKey(A,...)
    date=models.DateField()

class C(...):
    ...
    listOfB=models.ManyToManyField(C,...)

And this form:-

class SomeForm(BaseModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ('blocks',)

Now I am trying to create an object of C via a form through ajax post.

Before posting the data, I have this list called 
setofB = [ [id of A, some date], ...] that I add as a json data to the post as "&listOfB="+ string of setofB

But this is not working.

There is no selecting a set of pairs of Bs on the HTML side since the I need to convert the data myself and serialize it and pass it back to the server.

What am I doing wrong?